# Is it possible to recover account with no openid attached?

Tags: support

Is it possible to add this stack exchange account as openid for my old account[1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459706/ukasz-gruner)?
I, quite hastily, deleted gmail (ukaszg@gmail.com) - my only openid provider for stackoverflow.

What do I need to provide to proove ownership of that account? 
Or is there a hidden "old school" login page where I can type a password - so I could do this myself?

Comment: Visit this http://stackoverflow.com/contact/user-merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're still signed in to the old account on any machine, click "my logins" from your profile and add another set of credentials to retain access to that account.

If you can't do this anymore, hit up https://stackoverflow.com/contact/user-merge and drop us an email. We'll go from there.

Comment: thanks for speedy reply, but does that mean that I cannot merge without access to both email accounts?

Comment: @user225510 Not necessarily, but any sort of verification we do is best done in private over email rather than in public here on MSO.